How to Derive an Expression for First-Order Correction in Adiabatic Perturbation Theory?
I am reading the chapter titled Theory of Polarization: A Modern Approach by Raffaele Resta and David Vanderbilt, and I am trying to understand how to derive Equation (15) presented in the text. The equation describes the first-order correction to the wavefunction due to an adiabatic perturbation parameterized by $\lambda$
$$
|\delta \psi_{m \mathbf k} \rangle = -i\hbar \dot \lambda \sum_{m\neq n} {\langle \psi_{n\mathbf k}|\partial_\lambda \psi_{m\mathbf k}\rangle\over E_{n\mathbf k} - E_{m\mathbf k}}|\psi_{n\mathbf k}\rangle
$$
The text mentions that this follows from elementary adiabatic perturbation theory, but it does not provide a step-by-step derivation. Could someone please explain in detail how to derive this expression, possibly starting from the time-dependent Schrödinger equation or relevant perturbation theory concepts?

Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead.

Consider the time-dependent Schrodinger equation
$$
i\hbar |\dot\psi_m\rangle = H |\psi_m\rangle.
$$
If the state was an eigenvector of $H$, it would be easy to solve it. The solution would be something like $|\psi_m(t)\rangle = e^{-iE_m t/\hbar}|\psi_m\rangle$. Now, this is not the solution in general, but let suppose that we made the change of variables $|\phi_m(t)\rangle = e^{iE_mt/\hbar}|\psi_m(t)\rangle$. The equation turns to be
$$
i\hbar |\dot \phi(t)\rangle = (H-E_m)|\phi_m(t)\rangle.
$$
If the state $|\phi_m(t)\rangle$ was an eigenstate of $H$, everything was solved. But let's suppose it differs $|\delta\phi\rangle$ fromits eigenstate $|E_m(t)\rangle$ of $H$ at instant $t$. We could write $|E_m\rangle = |\phi_m(t)\rangle + |\delta\phi_m\rangle$, and by substitution on the r.h.s., we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
&i\hbar \partial_t |\phi_m\rangle = - (H-E_m)|\delta \phi_m\rangle \\ &\Rightarrow |\delta \phi_m \rangle = -i\hbar {1\over H-E_m}\partial_t |\phi_m\rangle = -i\hbar\sum_{m\neq n} {\langle \psi_n|\partial_t\phi_m\rangle\over E_n - E_m}|\psi_n\rangle.
\end{aligned}
$$
Where I inserted an identity in the last term, neglecting the component in the $m$ direction since it is zero.
Now, we back to $|\psi_m\rangle$ and use the fact that $\partial_t = \dot \lambda \partial_\lambda$ to prove the result.

Some remarks about my answer:

I never saw it in my life. I searched in all traditional books that I know, my last resource is aways the Landau books, but not even there. It seems a mix of time-dependent theory and adiabatic theorem.
The first substitution that I made is the interaction picture, very common in time-dependent perturbation theory. Usually it is used to get rid of the unperturbed part of the Hamiltonian, but here I used to get the operator $H-E_m$ instead of $H$ in the equations of motion. The advantage is that the first could always be assumed invertible, but the last not.
In the last equation was inserted an identity in the unperturbed basis, since the identity in the basis $|E_m\rangle$ would give higher order corrections
The adiabatic hypothesis consider that the Hamiltonian does not change in first order, this is why it was used $H$ all the time.
The use of the Kernel ${1\over H-E_m}$ is common in Wigner-Brillouin perturbation theory.

Answering OP's questions:

Why did you consider only a single state? The TDSE governs the time evolution for all states, in particular the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. I considered one unperturbed eigenstate, because we are searching for corrections of this eigenstate.
Motivation for writing $|E_m\rangle = |\phi_m\rangle + |\delta \phi_m\rangle $. The motivation is that the states unperturbed eigenstates $\phi_m\rangle$ needs some correction over the time evolution, and this correction is the whole point of the calculation. Now if I consider just first order perturbation, I can consider that the unperturbed state + the first order correction results in the actual eigenstate such that $H|E_m\rangle=E_m|E_m\rangle$. This procedure is standard in time-independent perturbation theory and you could easily find in standard text books.
Detailing the equation for $|\delta \phi_m\rangle$. You just need to substitute $|\phi_m\rangle$ by $|E_m\rangle - |\delta \phi_m\rangle$ and use the fact that $(H-E_m)|E_m\rangle = 0$. The whole of the kernel you could find out studying Brillouing-Wigner perturbation theory.


Thank you for your response! I have a few questions:


Choice of a Single State: The TDSE solution is generally a linear combination of eigenstates. Why did you consider only a single state ∣⟩


Motivation for Writing |Em⟩=|ϕm(t)⟩+|δϕm⟩
​What does this decomposition mean?


The equation iℏ∂t|ϕm⟩=−(H−Em)|δϕm⟩
and the expression for |δϕm⟩ involve non-trivial steps. Could you explain how these are derived and the role of 1/H−Em


Since I’m an undergraduate, a more detailed explanation of the reasoning and steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

I'll answer in the response
